# Select the most general machine learning model

Tags: machine-learning, model-selection, generalization

For example, let's say that model A had an average train auc of 0.82 and a test auc of 0.79 through cross-validation. The difference between the two scores is 0.03.
Let's say that model B has a train auc of 0.79 and a test auc of 0.78. The difference between the two scores is 0.01. The goal of machine learning is generalization.

As far as I know, the smaller the difference between train and test, the better the generalization in machine learning. Then, model B clearly has a smaller gap between train and test than Model A. So is Model B a better, more general model? Or is model A a superior model even if its test auc is 0.01 higher than model B?

To select a model statistically, obtain the confidence interval of the auc of the two models and compare them to select the model. However, the goals of traditional statistics and machine learning are different. So I'm confused what to do